# How to establish secure(SSL) connection to oracle database when using oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource?

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, ucp

My application uses oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource to connect to database.
Able to connect to database with normal connection.
How to establish secure SSL connection to oracle database?

Answer (score 0):

Can you review [JDBC developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/client-side-security.html#GUID-2BD2F189-A58C-4A85-8524-CFD9BB9AC575) for the instructions? You can also review this [technical brief](https://www.oracle.com/a/otn/docs/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf), it is old, but, you can still use it.

If you are using JKS or Oracle Wallets, you can also check out the [videos](https://youtu.be/Ds_xzaIqvtk) on [www.oracle.com/jdbc](http://www.oracle.com/jdbc).

Answer (score 0):

Just need to set PROTOCOL in connect string(url) to tcps and set truststore values in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Connection url should of the following format where we can mention protocol and port.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<server>)(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=<service name>)))
```